# Magento 2 Get Product By First 6 digit SKU

Tags: magento2, product, sku, magento2.3.5-p2

As stated in the title, I want to be able to get Product by only the first 6 digit SKU no

Full SKU No : 1350022021000

First 6 Digit SKU : 135002

I have done the code below to test if able to get the product just from the first 6 digits of SKU but apparently, it is not working as I wanted

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Custom\Controller\GoogleTagManager;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class GetProductData extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
            
        $sku  = "1350022021000"
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        // able to get the Product Details


        $sku  = "135002"
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        // not able to get , error as below appear

/// Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The product that was 
// requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. in 
// /var/www/html/my_system/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:276


    }

}
```

Any help is kindly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get product collection and then apply SKU filter matching the first digits.

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        
public function __construct(    
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;        
}

$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sku', ['like' => $firstSixDigitsOfSku.'%']);
```

Comment: Thank you, I finally able to get the SKU using this

Comment: $productcollection = $this->productCollection
->addAttributeToFilter([
    ['attribute' => 'sku', 'like' =>  $sku . '%']
])->load();

$sku = $productcollection->getData()[0]['sku'];

$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);